# Why when adding new properties to custom control the properties not show?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a library class and i added a new User Control and added a code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CustomControl
{
    public partial class ExtendedTextBox : UserControl
    {
        [PropertyTab("Data")]
        [Browsable(true)]
        [Category("Extended Properties")]
        [Description("Set TextBox border Color")]

        public string Texts
        {
            get { return textBox.Text; }
            set { textBox.Text = value; }
        }

        private TextBox textBox;

        public ExtendedTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.Multiline = true;
            textBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            this.Controls.Add(textBox);
        }

        private void ExtendedTextBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ExtendedTextBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        }

        private void ExtendedTextBox_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Size = new Size(this.Width - 3, this.Height - 2);
            textBox.Location = new Point(2, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

When i add the dll file to another windows forms project i drag the control to the designer but in the solution explorer under the control properties i don't see Data and not Extended Properties and not Set TextBox border Color.

I wanted to add a property that when you click on it will give you a sub property and click on that will open the colors pattern so you can change/set a new color to the paint event.

Now in the paint event it's set to Red but i want that there will be a property so the user can set any color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so understand what you tried. But works great for me, after some changes are needed in your code.

```
public partial class ExtendedTextBox : UserControl
{
    [PropertyTab("Data")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Extended Properties")]
    [Description("Set TextBox border Color")]
    public Color BorderColor { get; set; }

    [PropertyTab("Data")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Extended Properties")]
    [Description("Set TextBox Text")]
    public string Texts
    {
        get { return textBox.Text; }
        set { textBox.Text = value; }
    }

    private TextBox textBox;

    public ExtendedTextBox()
    {
        textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.Multiline = true;
        textBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        this.Controls.Add(textBox);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle, BorderColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);
        textBox.Size = new Size(this.Width - 3, this.Height - 2);
        textBox.Location = new Point(2, 1);
    }
}
```

**EDIT: For apply changes immediately**
you need refresh the control `BorderColor` property on catch the moment of set, which is not possible automatic property, but only full property. so:

```
//private field needy in full property.
private Color _BorderColor = Color.Red;  //= Color.Red; for default color...

[PropertyTab("Data")]
[Browsable(true)]
[Category("Extended Properties")]
[Description("Set TextBox border Color")]
public Color BorderColor
{
    get {return _BorderColor ;}
    set
    {
        _BorderColor = value;
        Invalidate(); //refresh, trigger new paint.
    }
}
```

Comment: lomed it's working but i have two questions: 1. How can i make that when i select new color property so it will change the border color at once after selection ? The way it is now only if i resize the textBox i see the changes of the selected color. 2. The property Texts is working but how can i make that also i will be able to enter text in the textBox area it self directly ? Now i can add/type text in the textBox only from the property Texts.

Comment: @DanielShpigel Please Accept the answer. for the questions: 1. i edited the answer for this 2. I do not think it's possible. Do you know an example where it works like this?.

Comment: Regarding the second question, I thought you mean in Desginer at Desgin time. if you mean in run-time like original TextBox, for me It works and is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Where is property that stores textBox border color? I see only `public string Texts` property. You should add new property for textBox border:

```
[PropertyTab("Data")]
[Browsable(true)]
[Category("Extended Properties")]
[Description("Set TextBox border Color")]
public Color BorderColor { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you defining the `Data` class that inherits `PropertyTab`? If you are not defining it yourself, what `Data` class did you expect for the designer to use?

The other attributes — `Category` and `Description` — work fine for me. The custom property is shown in the "Properties" tab of the `PropertyGrid` control, in its own "Extended Properties" category (naturally, you have to be grouping properties by category, not alphabetically), with the correct description text (shown when the property is selected in the `PropertyGrid`).

The `PropertyTab` attribute has to specify a valid `PropertyTab` class. If you don't have a `Data` class for it to use, then obviously the property can't be displayed in the `Data` class's property tab.